# inserting from Processing3.4 into HTML (java)

Tags: java, html, processing

I'm currently learning Processing to make 'art' using code (Java). However i'm now struggling to insert this .pde onto a web-page.

I've searched the web, but can't seem to find it.

- How do i insert the exported .pde file into my HTML.
- Are there any other solutions to this? Any tips always welcome!

.

```
static final int NUM_LINES = 10;

float t;                           // variable

void setup() {                    //Make
  background (20);
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw(){                    //Draw
  background(20);
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(5);

  translate(width/2, height/2);   //center point


  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LINES; i++) {
    line(x1(t + i), y1(t + i), x2(t + i), y2(t + i));              //drawing line
  }
  t+= 0.5;                                           //increment T 
}

float x1(float t) {
  return sin(t / 10) * 100 + sin(t / 15) * 100;
}

float y1(float t){
  return cos(t / 10) * 100;
}

float x2(float t) {
  return sin(t / 10) * 100 + sin(t / 15) * 100;
}

float y2(float t){
  return cos(t / 20) * 100 + cos (t / 12) * 20;
}
```

**Thanks guys!**

Comment: Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/processing-js) is a guide on using Processing.js to deploy a Processing sketch as a web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: You need processing.js to include the **Java** pde file in your HTML.

The background: Processing is based on the programming language Java. Basically, you cannot (or should not anymore) try to use Java in the browser. This might have been possible due to the usage of a class called Applet. But is not recommended and not supported by processing anymore.

The solution: If you want to use processing behaviour in a web browser, please refer to the JavaScript based implementation - ProcessingJS http://processingjs.org/

Here an excerpt from their page: http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html#whyprocessingjs

> Processing.js was originally created in order to allow existing Processing developers and existing Processing code (often referred to as sketches) to work unmodified on the web. As a result, the recommend way to use Processing.js is to write Processing code, and have Processing.js convert it to JavaScript before running it.

It provides several ways to get processing functionality to the web. You may find this options described here http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html#waystouseprocessingjs

For your special case you can find a section here for a quickstart. Mainly, you need to include the processing.js library and a canvas containing your pde - more information can be found in the [Quickstart Guide](http://processingjs.org/articles/p5QuickStart.html#quickstart):

```html
<script src="processing-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
<canvas data-processing-sources="<your-pde-file>.pde"></canvas>
```

HTH, Sabine

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful

Comment: @NinoV.Gerwen Good luck with your project. If the answer helped you, please consider to mark it correct.